# Netty Websockets, is it possible to have the server wait for client response

Tags: websocket, netty

I am stuck trying to figure out how to implement a request-response going from netty websocket server to client, and then having the server handle the response maybe using `channel future` or something else in java.

I saw how to do the same using the client sending a request to server, and handling the response - but not the other way round.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
You need to make a connection to the client, and create a new handler, in that handler when it starts, you will write to the specific ip, you will need the ip of the client.

Quick recap:

1) Make a connection to the server (with the client).

2) Let the server create a handler for the client, (TIP: Try to set the ip as a parameter (Type: String))

3) Let the server write something first.

4) Let the client interact with it.

5) (Optional)See if the client needs to write something back.

6) (Optional)Let the server respond.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for that. I already have netty setup and I can send messages to the client, the client can then send messages back. What Im trying to do is send messages to a group of clients and handle the responses. basically Im asking the 3 clients to give me a random number, and then i want to sum these numbers up and send to the server, i need to do this every 100ms, so was using a thread executor, with a future.. but thats doesnt work. Im now thinking the only way maybe to a new channel handler for this specific request respsonse...

Comment: Well, You will need to create a function, it has 3 parameters, these are from the 3 clients, so you have a "public void sum(int c1,int c2,int c3" c stands for client :) and when you get the random number, you store it in a variable in that class from the sum function (it would be best to be have it static)  then you make a timer that runs every 100ms and you put the function sum in there with the random number from the client.

You get what i'm trying to say?

Comment: Thanks Arno, I understand what your saying. I was just trying to avoid having to go via the handlers on client response, but i dont think its possible to do it anyother way.